# unset($_SESSION["valid_user"]) error

Tags: php, function, unset

I am trying to un-register my session by writing:

```
unset($_SESSION["valid_user"])
```

And it gives me the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) in D:\xampp\htdocs\compartElinks\logout.php on line 7

Here is my code:

```
<?

// include function files for this application
require_once("bookmark_fns.php");
session_start();
$old_user = $_SESSION["valid_user"];  // store  to test if they *were* logged in
$result_unreg = unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
$result_dest = session_destroy();

...
```

Full Code: http://pastebin.com/NBP7C3th

How to solve that?

Comment: check the line above it and make sure it has a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Show the rest of you code.

Comment: The return result of calling `unset` is void. Since it doesnt return anything it makes no sense to try and assign the return result to a variable.  It being a language construct, I believe that's probably your issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result_unreg = unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
```

`unset` has no return value (`void`) and cannot be assigned to a variable.

It is a language construct, just like `isset()` and `include`.

As you might have read in the comments, there are a few functions in PHP which differ from normal functions. [A list of them can be found here.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
>   which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but
>   they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any
>   of the following words as constants, class names, function or method
>   names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
>   confusion.

Comment: yes, but include() and isset() have return values, which can be captured and checked. unset is documented as returning void, but that nowhere does it say you can't have a (pointless) return-assign construct using it.

Comment: That's right Marc. Of course `$x = IreturnVoid();` works. I think the combination of beeing a special *function* and returning void issues the error.

Comment: yeah. `$foo = echo 'bar'` spews the same error. but echo is a language construct, unset seems to be a proper function. `unset $bar` fails, while `echo $bar` works fine. Gotta love PHP's extreme devotion to internal consistency...

Comment: Just tried the same, `unset $bar;` ... need to get used to those.